# No suitable driver found for jdbc java Tomcat 8

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat, jdbc

Trying to connect my java web application to mysql database using tomcat 8 server and getting same error every time: No suitable driver found for jdbc

this is my method that is trying to connect to database

```
  public String kreiraj() {

      String g="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
 //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   System.out.println("Connecting database...");

     String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fc";
     String user = "root";
     String password = "";
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)) {
        System.out.println("Database connected!");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot connect the database!", e);
    }
    return "index"; }
```

If I start same code as standard java application it work and it connects to database without any problems.
So I figured that the problem must be something with tomcat 8 server. I tried every possible solution there is and im still getting same error.
I tried this things:

1. adding mysql connector jar file to build path
2. adding mysql connector to WEB-INF/lib folder of my web application
3. adding mysql connector to tomcat 8 lib folder
4. tried using `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`  but getting classnotfound error

Nothing seems to work and im starting to lose my mind. If anyone know solution it would be great. Ty

Comment: Are you including your server library in your project?

Comment: yes I do , http://i.imgur.com/NGUlOi4.png

Comment: @MEGAMAN how about try removing project from tomcat and changing port number to 3307 in both Tomcat and set to String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/fc"; and then add project back onto Tomcat start again. I realise you can get a connection running as Java application but all other steps you've taken look appropriate so not sure what else you could do other than try removing and then adding project again

Comment: @MEGAMAN .. can you try using [JNDI DBCP](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-configure-tomcat-dbcp-connection-pool-pooling-postgres)?

Comment: Have you tried both 2 and 4 together?

Comment: I did try both 2 and 4 together, I actually tried every possible combination of steps above. I installed newest eclipse now, added new tomcat server and still the same problem. I will try to set up connection like garry mentioned. Thx everybody for help.

Comment: Alright, I dont know what was the problem but I just switched back to netbeans and glashfish server and everything works fine now.